# Why some apps still able to create directory/ files in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory/ Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory?

Tags: android

I thought currently, all apps Google Play store, suppose not able to create directory/ files in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` / `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`?

Since Android 11, We are encouraged to only use

```
Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

---

In my Android 11 device

`Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` will return

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/
```

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will return

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Music")` will return

```
/storage/emulated/0/Music
```

---

I notice majority sound recording apps in the market, still able to write to **storage/emulated/0**, after gaining `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` runtime permission.

For instance

1. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrwq.recorder able write to **/storage/emulated/0/SmartMob/SmartRecorder** directory - https://i.stack.imgur.com/x06nt.png
2. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=myrecorder.voicerecorder.voicememos.audiorecorder.recordingapp able write to **/storage/emulated/0/Music/MyRecorder** - https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Nvd.png

---

I have written a quick code snippet to try. I have confirmed by using a norm way, it seems like it is not able to create directory/ file using path returned by `Environment`.

```
// Prior running the following code, I have grant WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE runtime permission.

// "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Cheok"
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Music"), "Cheok/");

// All returns false!！
Log.i("CHEOK", file + " exists " + file.exists());
Log.i("CHEOK", file + " mkdirs " + file.mkdirs());
Log.i("CHEOK", file + " exists " + file.exists());
```

---

Do you have any idea, what technique these apps are using, which makes them able to write to location like **/storage/emulated/0/SmartMob/SmartRecorder**, **/storage/emulated/0/Music/MyRecorder**, ... ?

By doing so, this gives a huge advantage, where the app data is retained, after the app is uninstalled.

Comment: If their targetSDKVersion is 29 or lower they don't have to use the newer scopes storage.  New apps aren't allowed to do that, but existing apps that were already uploaded can.  Of course if they push an update they're forced to upgrade to a newer target

Comment: With MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE apps can create folders and files everywhere.

Comment: All apps can create folders and files in public directories like Music and Documents without any special permission. Your app too.

Comment: It makes sense for folder `/storage/emulated/0/Music/MyRecorder`, because "Music" is one of the few allowable public folder name. But, how about `/storage/emulated/0/SmartMob/SmartRecorder` ?